# Is it safe if I delete table actionscheduler_actions.ibd to my wordpress?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

Due preloading wp-rocket, the table `actionscheduler_actions.ibd` became  large with thousand of content.

I checked the order of the 40 largest files in the directory `/var` with this command : `du -a /var | sort -n -r | head -n 40`

The screenshot I took shows that there is a Mysql file from `1` domain that went to large because preloading feature by `wp-rocket`.

Now, I have uninstalled `wp-rocket` but so much data, made by wp-rocket, has being recorded to table `wpxj_actionscheduler_actions.ibd`.

I want to delete only table created by that plugin, but I don't know to do that from phpMyAdmin.

The location is `/var/lib/mysql/db_domainname/wpxj_actionscheduler_actions.ibd` (please, look at `ss`, I think it's very large size for only 1 table mysql).

[image: actionscheduler_actions.ibd file size]

If I delete this file, `wpxj_actionscheduler_actions.ibd`, through SSH, will my domain happening crash or error?

How to delete table created only by wp-rocket in this file ? Would anyone can give me suggestion to fix this?

Comment: You shouldn't delete table body files directly, this will cause problems up to MySQL crash during the service starting. You'd drop this table with according query. But firstly you must ensure that it does not interfere with any other object in your databases (there is no foreign keys to it, it is not mentioned in stored objects and so on...) and it is not used in the queries executed in your applications as rowsource.

Answer (score 0):

Do not delete the file on disk. That will cause corruption in your database; even if you don't intend to use that specific table it's likely that MySQL will try to refer to that table and will not start correctly or will have data errors.

In most default installations, MySQL generally doesn't give back disk space that it has previously used; even if you delete the table from within MySQL. However, it seems to me like your installation is configured differently and you might automatically get that disk space back if you delete that table. However, you risk causing data reference integrity problems. I don't know anything about that plugin so you could check with the plugin authors for information about how to remove the plugin and that table without causing issues with the rest of your data. It could be that dropping that table is all that's needed, but I'm not sure.

You can sometimes reclaim space by using the OPTIMIZE TABLE command, which is available graphically from the Operations tab of each table within phpMyAdmin. That will only bring back space that isn't being used (for example, if you delete a lot of rows); so it is not very useful by itself if you haven't removed any data from the table inside MySQL, but if you restructure your database, remove some rows, or truncate the table this can help get some disk space back.